# How to delete custom field translations when deleting the field?

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, translation, destructivechanges.xml

I've deleted a custom field, and pushed that to my scratch org, but now I can't delete the corresponding translation:

```bash
$ rm package/main/default/objects/Opportunity/fields/MyField__c.field-meta.xml

$ sfdx project deploy start -o splyza-scratch
=== Pushed Source

 STATE   FULL NAME TYPE        PROJECT PATH
 ─────── ───────── ─────────── ────────────
 Deleted MyField   CustomField package\main\default\Opportunity\fields\MyField__c…

$ rm package/main/default/objectTranslations/Opportunity-ja/MyField__c.fieldTranslation-meta.xml

$ sfdx project deploy start -o splyza-scratch
Error (1): Unexpected child metadata [package\main\default\objectTranslations\Opportunity-ja\MyField__c.fieldTranslation-meta.xml] found for parent type [CustomObjectTranslation]
```

As you can see, I get the following error:

> Error (1): Unexpected child metadata [package\main\default\objectTranslations\Opportunity-ja\MyField__c.fieldTranslation-meta.xml] found for parent type [CustomObjectTranslation]

How do I delete the translation? The field and every reference to it have already been deleted, so I can't understand why SFDX thinks I should retain the translation.